# Failed to cast Dynamic Table entity to custom Entity Azure Table storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to Replace an entity on my table based on Partition Key and Row key retrieve the entity successfully but when i try to cast it, it throws an invalid cast exception.
I looked at the MSDN docs and that is the correct way to delete, even made sure to follow the guidelines for Creating an entity

> Entity properties you'd like to store in a table must be public properties of the type, and support both getting and setting of values. Also, your entity type must expose a parameter-less constructor

This is my class

```
    public class BasicAsset : TableEntity
{
    public BasicAsset()
    {
    }

    public BasicAsset(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }


    [IsFilterable, IsSortable, IsSearchable]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [IsFilterable, IsSortable]
    public int Version { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my code at the point of the exception

```
TableOperation retreiveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve("Orginization", result.Results[0].Document.RowKey);
TableResult toDelete = await table.ExecuteAsync(retreiveOperation);
BasicAsset toReplaceAsset = (BasicAsset) toDelete.Result;
//Change what is new here
toReplaceAsset.Version = asset.Version;
TableOperation replaceOperation = TableOperation.Replace(toReplaceAsset);
```

The error

```
   e = {System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity' to type 'AssetSynch.Models.BasicAsset'.
   at AssetSynch.Controllers.TableStorageViewFunctions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<UpdateLattestAssetVe...
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `Retrieve` try using `Retrieve<BasicAsset>`, alternatively you could simply call `ExecuteQuery<BasicAsset>`